# monkjs find - exclude fields and use options

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[Monk](https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk) has the following syntax for find method

`db.get("collection").find( data, options, function );`

For excluding a field one has to use -field instead of options:

`db.get("collection").find( data, "-field", function );`

What I don't understand where do I put object with options, as function takes only 3 arguments if I understand correctly. I tried different combinations trying to stuff two values into array, but it didn't work.

Comment: Just checkig out Seems to be ab array, I would try with ["-field1", "-field2"]

Comment: ["-field1", "-field2"] works to exclude fields. What I want to do is use options for example limit. If there was no exclusion I would use .find({data:1}, {limit:20}, function); but instead of limit I chose to exclude field and don't have a way to limit anymore

Comment: One question, besides you use this framework, I don't see any benefits of using this complex syntax, for this kind of queries it's simple to use Mongo queries.